# Karaf feature:install throws Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1

Tags: karaf, camunda

I am new to Karaf and trying to learn how to handle it.
On the way I tried to add Camunda features.
Like described on https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform-osgi/tree/master/camunda-bpm-karaf-feature

at first, I added the repo:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.camunda.bpm.extension.osgi/camunda-bpm-karaf-feature/4.1.0/xml/features
```

then I tried to install them;

```
feature:install camunda-bpm-karaf-feature-full
```

unfortunately I got this Exception

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to build resource for mvn:xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:82)
at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:67)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.prepare(SubsystemResolver.java:180)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:379)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1025)
at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:964)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
    at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.doBuild(ResourceBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.resource.ResourceBuilder.build(ResourceBuilder.java:80)
    ... 9 more
Error executing command: Unable to build resource for mvn:xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1: Unsupported 'Bundle-ManifestVersion' value: 1
```

I am using Karaf version 4.2.1
Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the features depend on [xmlpull 1.1.3.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1) which has `Manifest-Version: 1.0` in MANIFEST.MF thus making it an OSGi R3 bundle.

Apache Felix supports bundles conforming the OSGi Release 4 (or newer) only (`Manifest-Version: 2.0`) which is why it rejects xmlpull. See the Felix [source](https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/trunk/utils/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/utils/resource/ResourceBuilder.java#L86) for reference.

If you control the source consider wrapping xmlpull and installing the wrapped bundle from the features. You can also play around with the Karaf console; for example, `install -s wrap:mvn:xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1`.